# Unrooting Galaxy Nexus - dies when plugged in

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, unrooting

I rooted my Galaxy Nexus (Verizon) in order to get Jelly Bean. I got more than I wanted. The issues that have come from this are horrible. Whenever I plug my phone into a computer - it dies. It won't boot until I unplug it. I installed what I thought was a stock ROM of Jelly Bean (it was AOKP which has no way of installing apps), and now I'm completely stuck. I can't boot into recovery mode. I can't flash any ROMs to it and I can't plug it into a computer to run the Nexus Toolkit.

I just want to get back the official Jelly Bean OS. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the Android SDK installed, particularly the `fastboot` tool.  (You probably have this already if you've rooted your phone.)

Go to [Google's factory images page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), find the section called "mysid" near the bottom, and download the 4.0.4 file.

Turn your phone off, then hold both the Volume Up and Down buttons, and press and hold the Power button.  You should see the phone's bootloader screen, which looks like a green droid with its front panel open, and an arrow at the top that says Start.  Don't press any buttons here, but plug in your USB cable.

Extract the factory image file that you downloaded.  Inside, you should find a file called `image-mysid-imm76k.zip`.  Open a command prompt, `cd` to the folder with that file, and run `fastboot -w update image-mysid-imm76k.zip`.  That'll reflash the phone's factory software image, which should put it back to normal.  (You'll be running ICS at this point, but you can do the Jelly Bean OTA upgrade afterward if it's available to you.)

This may wipe all your phone's data — including the "SD card" internal memory — so make a backup of anything important first.

---

If your AOKP "has no way of installing apps", it sounds like when you installed it, you forgot to install the "gapps" add-on, which includes the Play app as well as other Google apps like Gmail.  But the other problems you described shouldn't happen — I've put AOKP on my Galaxy Nexus and it works fine.  If you still have problems after flashing the factory image, you'll need to provide more detailed information about what's happening.

Comment: You can use an alternative market (say, F-Droid) without Google Play installed. OP will just have to allow unknown sources.

Comment: I can't plug the phone in. It will kill it instantly and then it won't boot until I unplug it. I was able to get back to the Jelly Bean ROM by downloading Clockworkmod from the web browser. I just need a way to put it back to stock WITHOUT it being connected to a computer (I have move files over wirelessly).

Comment: You say it "won't boot", but have you tried what I described?  Stopping at the bootloader is different from trying to boot the Android OS.  If even that doesn't work, it sounds like a hardware problem, because flashing AOKP doesn't change the bootloader.  Anyway, if you can get to CWM, did you make a nandroid backup of your original ROM?  If so, just restore that.

Comment: I cannot get it to that boot screen in any situation, whether it's plugged in or not. I did not make a nandroid backup of my original ROM. I didn't realize it would be so important. I don't know where to find an original ROM.

Comment: Well, I provided a link to Google's page with the original ROM (and now the 4.1 one is available there too).  You don't *need* a nandroid backup; that's just an alternative that would've let you avoid wiping your data too.  You may find [these directions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1626895) more helpful than mine, but if you truly can't get into bootloader mode, then a) something is seriously wrong with your phone, and b) you're probably hosed.

Comment: Oh, one other thing to try:  on your phone's shutdown menu (the one you get when you hold the power button), is there a "reboot" option?  CyanogenMod has one that lets you reboot directly into bootloader mode, and I think AOKP does too, though I'm not sure.  That might work if the volume+power button combination doesn't.